# How to search and replace a column in a CSV via perl?

Tags: perl, csv, replace

So, I'm super new to perl... I'm on a windows box within a Corporate network. I am unable to download CPAN modules...

I have a CSV that is exported with multiple columns, the 2nd column contains 2 rows with text and the rest of the rows are IP addresses. I need to change the first 3 octets of the IP for all the rows excluding the text obviously. I then need to either save it to the same file, or create a new one... I also need all the other columns to remain in the document. I've looked and looked and everyone suggests modules which makes sense but I cannot get them. Here is my code:

```
if ( $cmd[0] eq "update" ) {
    print "Old subnet ex: 10.0.0\n";
    my $oldsubnet = <STDIN>;
    chomp $oldsubnet;
    print "New subnet ex: 10.0.0\n";
    my $newsubnet = <STDIN>;
    chomp $newsubnet;

    my $file = "path\\file.csv";

    open( my $fh, '<', $file ) or die "'$file' would not open $!";

    while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
        chomp $line;
        my @fields = split ",", $line;
        my $string = $fields[1];

        $string =~ s/$oldsubnet/$newsubnet/g;

        my $ofile = "path\\test.csv";

        open( my $ofh, '>>', $ofile ) or die "'$ofile' would not open $!";
        print $ofh "$string\n";
    }
}
```

So I just end up with a single column with the updated IP's with this code. How in the world do I get the rest of the CSV... Is there an easier way to just replace the IP's???? It seems like this would be easy but the CSV is making it hard. Any help would be appreciated. P.S. I am using strict and warnings :)

So just to clarify I am aware that @fields is being left out and thus not being printed... What I'm asking is how do I update only the data in the 2nd column and then put the whole document back into a new file?

Comment: You only ever output `$string`. How do you expect to see the rest of `@fields`?

Comment: I have pointed that out in my question... Do you have a solution on how to get the @fields back into the document while also updating the IP's in column 2?

Answer (score 0):

You need to output more than just the changed field...

```
my @fields = split(/,/, $line);
$fields[1] =~ s/$oldsubnet/$newsubnet/g;
print $ofh join(',', @fields);
```

Also, don't open the output file in the loop to read the input file.

Answer (score 0):

Without your source CSV, I can't say for sure, but would be thinking "use the `Text::CSV` module":

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;

print "Old subnet ex: 10.0.0\n";
my $oldsubnet = <STDIN>;
chomp $oldsubnet;
print "New subnet ex: 10.0.0\n";
my $newsubnet = <STDIN>;
chomp $newsubnet;

my $file  = "path\\file.csv";
my $ofile = "path\\test.csv";

open( my $input,  '<', $file )  or die "'$file' would not open $!";
open( my $output, '>', $ofile ) or die "'$ofile' would not open $!";
my $csv = Text::CSV->new( { binary => 1, eol => "\n" } );

while ( my $row = $csv->getline() ) {
    $row->[1] =~ s/$oldsubnet/$newsubnet/;
    $csv->print( $output, $row );
}
```

It's not always the best answer, but where you're trying to read CSV, change a single field, and write CSV it works quite nicely.